# Pdf Library for Monotouch and Monodroid

Tags: pdf, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, pdf-reader

I'm looking to build an app that will be used to show pdf's for Windows Phone, Android, and iOS.  Are there any libraries that will work for both monodroid and monotouch and provide a GUI widget.

I have done some research around some of various pdf libraries, and it looks like there is a lot of code that is naively done to keep the speed of rendering high for pdfs.  I think that is making it hard to have/find a shared library that will work for all of the devices.  I want to confirm that this is the case.

Thanks in advance.